# how to parent a rigged grop of object using constraints to another object without messing up the constraint

Tags: rigging, constraints, parent

i just rigged a fighter jet but forgot to add the engine nozzle to the rig or the empty . so here are the 2 different rigged objects [image] i want to make them move together so i selected the entire engine parts and parented it to the main rig as expected i just messed it up . i dont want to re do the whole engine again . please tell me how can i parent the 2 sets of objects without messing up with anything .

Comment: If the main body section of the aircraft already has a parent holding it all together, the cube,  and assuming you haven't already done so do the same with the engine parts?  Give them their own parent? 

With both sections/groups having their respective parent to hold them together as two separate sections, add a 3rd and "Master" parent and make the 1st two parents, children of that.  Disable selectability of everything except the master parent so they can't be inadvertently pulled apart.

The aircraft is then dragged, rotated etc by ONLY the Master Parent.

Comment: Cont... When flaps, undercarraige, canopy, etc are to be animated, switch their Outliner arrows back on, keyframe each piece as required, then toggle the arrows off again.  Each movement will be 'local' to their respective parent, and of course the main parent.

Comment: well the engine is really complex and it is a working engine that is , it can do trust vectoring when scaling a main empty . and parenting it to an empty just makes it look fully dismantled , but i noticed that if i select all the parts of the engine and grab it it moves very well and doesn't hamper with the constraint is there any feature in blender other than parenting that a group of objects can be moved when a desired object is selected ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

close observation shows that your flaps control surface all are rigged and are parented to the box empty and it moves along with the rig and what you want is that the engine parts that you have made in another blend file that was imported to the current blend file needs to also follow along with the body. well parenting doesn't hold good for these things since it just messes up everything be it the constraints etc.

you can use group instancing over here, heres how:

so what you do is first **select all the parts of the engine** and **press ctrl g** and the press **shift a** and select **group instance** you will see a replica of your engine parented to an empty axis use the empty to position the replica in the desired position. and with the replica selected click on the main empty and **parent it  to the empty using keep transform option**. now you will see that along with the body the replica engine also moves when you move the empty. now you may notice that all the objects in the replica object look to be joined together to form a single object but you can edit every single object it by editing the actual engine you can even scale the thrust controller empty and you will notice that even the replica will be able to do the trust vectoring, hope it worked, thanks and bye.

Comment: man i just followed everything what you said and it worked so well . thanks a lot .

Comment: glad to hear that you have got the answer